# Stack Exchange™ Piled Spaces™ made super-short answers possible

Tags: bug, answers, answer-length

We all know that comments can't be shorter than 15 chars, and "inflating" comments with spaces isn't possible. For example, your web page may allow you to submit this comment, but the server rejects it:

```
A                           B
```

However, it appears that the 30-char restriction for answers **CAN** be bypassed this way, so this is a valid, submittable answer:

```
Yes                                      !
```

Example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52663293) (10k on Stack Overflow), or try submitting one by yourself in the sandbox.

Comment: Such an answer would quickly get flagged as low-quality by the system and get deleted by reviewers quickly.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog But since the safeguard for comments already exists, would it make sense that one for answer doesn't?

Comment: Yeah, you make a good point, but comments have more safeguards because they aren't reviewed.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog Just FYI, review queues are bad at time sensitivity. You can only expect that answers like `Yes!` be deleted **quickly** by three 20k users or a ♦ if they happen to be in a chatroom like SOCVR or SOBotics. This well invalidates the "comments aren't reviewed" point.

Comment: I was referring to the Low Quality Posts review queue.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog Even if it's LQP, it requires 6 delete votes (4 on SO), which is still rather slow compared to 20ks' deletion.

Comment: Yes the Low Quality queue is one safeguard against this, but why wouldn't you want to prevent such answers from hitting the queue at all? On the other hand, we could just put in [hyphens instead of spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316363/273494) to pass the check right? I think it makes a lot of sense to conflate redundant characters before counting, but I'm not sure how tricky it would be to do the conflation without affecting the formatting.

Comment: @ColleenV Repeating characters are caught by SmokeDetector.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog That doesn't keep the answer from being posted. My point with the hyphens thing is that fixing the spaces thing doesn't really do much to fix the problem, if it even is a problem. We could do more to keep low quality stuff from even hitting the queues, but if we're going to put forth the effort, it should have meaningful impact. Those repeating characters are valid markup though...